# When sending an Auth0 passwordless email link, how do you set the redirect uri?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, auth0

I am creating users via the C# Management Api. Using passwordless, this automatically causes an email to go out. That part works great!

When I click the link in the email, it pops up my Auth0 instance, and I'm getting the "Oops! Something went wrong" message... In the querystring, I can clearly see that redirect_uri is empty, and I assume that must be the problem. Hitting F12, this seems to be confirmed - it's failing on something called VerifyRedirect.

So how do I set this redirect_uri?  I am using the C# SDK, and I don't see a way to set it in UserCreateRequest. I also don't see it in the dashboard. What am I missing?

Here's my test code:

```
 var request = new UserCreateRequest()
 {
     Connection = "email",
     Email = email,
     EmailVerified = false,
     VerifyEmail = true,
     FirstName = first,
     LastName = last,
     FullName = first + " " + last,                                
     AppMetadata = new
     {
         roles = "Admin"
     }
 };

 // Just dodging async while I test - remember, this part works.
 var result = client.Users
                    .CreateAsync(request)
                    .GetAwaiter()
                    .GetResult();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you create an user via the management API, the redirect URI is set to the first available callback URLs in your client. You can check the client ID in the query string to determine the client and add the redirect URI in its settings.

Note that you don't have to actually create a user like this to start the passwordless flow on an email. If you use the [Passwordless​Email​Request](http://auth0.github.io/auth0.net/api/Auth0.AuthenticationApi.Models.PasswordlessEmailRequest.html) object, you can set the client ID and redirect URI (inside AuthenticationParameters) explicitly, so they will not be implicitly deduced.

Comment: Ah, good to know! So I can create a regular database user, and then do a PasswordlessEmailRequest whenever I want? That is probably what I should do - thanks!

Comment: You don't need to create a database user. Database and passwordless users are mutually exclusive. Simply doing a Passwordless request without creating a user first, will automatically create the user for you.

Comment: @thameera I'm not seeing passwordless create a user (until the user follows the link through)

Comment: Do you need to cycle your application or something? I added a new callback url to the front of the list, but it always sets the redirect url to the old/second url. If I remove the second/old URL from the list, I get redirected to an error page stating that the old URL isn't in the list!

Comment: @weberc2 that's probably a bug - would be good to either create a support ticket or raise in auth0 community forum.